# Building SOA Composite application using Ant

Tags: ant, soa

I am tring to write an ant script to build a SOA composite application.

I have written the script as follows -

```
<project name="SOA-Build" default="sca-package" basedir=".">
<description> Automated Build file for SOA composite application </description>

<!-- import global properties for this build -->
<property file="build.properties"/>

<target name="init">
    <delete dir="./${sca_name}/deploy" />
    <delete dir="./logs" />
    <mkdir dir="./${sca_name}/deploy" />
    <mkdir dir="./logs" />
</target>

<target name="sca-compile" depends="init">
    <ant antfile="${soa_home}/bin/ant-sca-compile.xml" inheritAll="false">
        <property name="wl_home" value="${weblogic_home}"/>
        <property name="scac.input" value="./${sca_name}/composite.xml"/>
        <property name="scac.output" value="./logs/out.xml" />
        <property name="scac.error" value="./logs/out.err" />
        <property name="scac.application.home" value="."/>
    </ant>
</target>

<target name="sca-package" depends="sca-compile">
    <ant antfile="${soa_home}/bin/ant-sca-package.xml" inheritAll="false">
        <property name="compositeDir" value="./${sca_name}"/>
        <property name="compositeName" value="${sca_name}"/>
        <property name="revision" value="${rev_id}"/>
        <property name="sca.application.home" value="."/>
    </ant>
</target>

</project>
```

the build.properties file contains

```
sca_name=my_processes
rev_id=1.0
weblogic_home=C:\\Oracle\\Middleware\\home_ps2
soa_home=C:\\Oracle\\Middleware\\home_ps2\\Oracle_SOA1
```

while running ant I am getting following error in ant-sca-package.xml

```
 [scac]  error: BPM-71504: Unexpected error parsing 'oramds:/soa/shared/work
 flow/TaskEvidenceService.xsd'.  Cause: oracle.mds.exception.MDSException: MDS-00
 054: The file to be loaded oramds:/soa/shared/workflow/TaskEvidenceService.xsd d
 oes not exist..  Action: Verify that file is valid and accessible

 [scac]  error: BPM-71504: Unexpected error parsing 'oramds:/soa/shared/work
 flow/WorkflowCommon.xsd'.  Cause: oracle.mds.exception.MDSException: MDS-00054:
 The file to be loaded oramds:/soa/shared/workflow/WorkflowCommon.xsd does not ex
 ist..  Action: Verify that file is valid and accessible

 [scac]  error: BPM-71504: Unexpected error parsing 'oramds:/soa/shared/work
 flow/WorkflowTask.xsd'.  Cause: oracle.mds.exception.MDSException: MDS-00054: Th
 e file to be loaded oramds:/soa/shared/workflow/WorkflowTask.xsd does not exist.
 .  Action: Verify that file is valid and accessible
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like I have sorted out this problem.

If you are faceing similar problems while calling **ant-sca-package.xml** from your build.xml script

1. open **ant-sca-package.xml**
2. modify **scac-validate** task and **remove/comment-out**

   ```
   < antcall target="scac" inheritall="true"/>
   ```
3. run your build script

This might solve the problem.

Thanks,

Arpan

Comment: I can confirm this does solve the problem.  However, I would be interested in any way to bypass the oracle validation that did not involve editing the premade scripts.

Comment: i am getting the same exception while invocation of ant-compile .. but i didn't find anything in ant-sca-compile to comment out.
Please advise what to do in case of ant-sca-compile.

Comment: Confirmed in my environment. After commeting out that line the packages are being compiled.